# Shout on Venue Page

Tags: api, foursquare

I am new to the foursquare api. What I am doing is allowing a user that is a manager of a Venue to link to our app. Choose which venue (if they have multiple) they want to use with our app and we post pageupdates/shouts on their behalf. The problem is these shouts do NOT show up when regular users view the public Venue page, but if I am logged in as the manager, switch to using 4Square as the Venue (using the yellow bar) then I CAN see the updates my app posts.

What is the reason for why I can't see the posts when not viewing the site as the Venue?

I am hitting this URL https://api.foursquare.com/v2/pageupdates/add?v=20121105
and passing in the shout,pageId,venueId,broadcast=private parameters as per their documentation.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok right after posting this it appears the broadcast=private will actually mark the update as private. The documentation is slightly misleading. You need to omit the parameter to just do a regular shout update. You can still specify facebook|twitter is you want to make use of the linking of accounts.

Bottom line: if you want to just post a shout, omit the broadcast parameter...

Yay me!....